# iPhone Development - Keyboard does not automatically adjust when taking input using TextField placed in a TableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, keyboard, adjustment

I just downloaded 2.2.1 and i've seen that my input view does not adjust itself when an input field (NSTextField) is selected. Earlier the view was adjusting itself w.r.t keyboard.

I was using 2.1. How can i achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug, which has been fixed by Apple.